# D3.js - Working with major and minor gridlines

Tags: d3.js, charts, axis

I'm trying to get major and minor gridlines in my chart, but have run into a very odd problem...

My approach is the same as in this bl.ock - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349486. Use two axis instances, one for the ticks with labels and one for the grid. Set the grid axis to have twice as many ticks as the labelled axis, and use the exit selection of the data join to style the minor gridlines. This should give you one minor gridline between each major.

The problem is my code produces a chart with too many of the gridlines styled as minor. But, if you modify the y-domain to be [-1, 1] instead of the extent of the data (Line 112: https://jsfiddle.net/z3r8ewmL/2/), it works just fine.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function AreaPlot(width, height) {

  // Scoping
  var self = this;


  // Plotting variables
  this.margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  };

  this.animation_duration = 250;
  this.width = width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  this.height = height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

  // Plotting functions
  this.build_x_axis = function() {

    // Create the function that maps from data space to display space
    self.x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, self.width]);

    // Create the axis function
    self.x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .ticks(10)
      .scale(self.x)
      .orient('bottom');

    // Add the axis
    self.x_axis_g = self.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + self.height + ')')
      .call(self.x_axis);

    // Create the grid function
    self.x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
      .ticks(20)
      .scale(self.x)
      .orient('bottom')
      .tickSize(-self.height);

    // Add the grid
    self.x_grid_g = self.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x grid')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + self.height + ')')
      .call(self.x_grid);

    // Style the grid
    self.style_x_grid(self.x_grid_g);

  };

  this.build_y_axis = function() {

    // Create the function that maps from data space to display space
    self.y = d3.scale.linear().range([self.height, 0]);

    // Create the axis function
    self.y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .ticks(10)
      .scale(self.y)
      .orient('left');

    // Add the axis
    self.y_axis_g = self.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(self.y_axis);

    // Create the grid function
    self.y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
      .ticks(20)
      .scale(self.y)
      .orient('left')
      .tickSize(-self.width);

    // Add the grid
    self.y_grid_g = self.svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y grid')
      .call(self.y_grid);

    // Style the grid
    self.style_y_grid(self.y_grid_g);


  };

  this.domain_value = function(data_point, index) {

    return self.x(index + 1);

  };

  this.defined = function(data_point) {

    return data_point;

  };

  this.range_value = function(data_point, index) {

    return self.y(data_point);

  };

  this.set_data = function(data) {

    // Update data extents
    self.x.domain([0, data.length]);
    self.y.domain(d3.extent(data));
    // self.y.domain( [-1, 1] ); // The plot works just fine with this domain...

    // Update line
    self.update_line(data);

    // Update axes
    self.update_axes();

  };

  this.style_x_grid = function(g) {

    g.selectAll('.tick')
      .data(self.x.ticks(10), function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .exit()
      .classed('minor', true);

  };

  this.style_y_grid = function(g) {

    g.selectAll('.tick')
      .data(self.y.ticks(10), function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .exit()
      .classed('minor', true);

  };

  this.update_axes = function() {

    self.x_axis_g
      .transition().duration(self.animation_duration)
      .call(self.x_axis);
    self.y_axis_g
      .transition().duration(self.animation_duration)
      .call(self.y_axis);

    self.x_grid_g.transition()
      .duration(self.animation_duration)
      .call(self.x_grid);
    self.y_grid_g.transition()
      .duration(self.animation_duration)
      .call(self.y_grid);

    self.style_x_grid(self.x_grid_g);
    self.style_y_grid(self.y_grid_g);

  };

  this.update_line = function(data) {

    var plot = self.svg.selectAll('.line')
      .data([data]);

    // Add elements when new data is present
    plot.enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line');

    // Set the data attribute
    plot.transition().duration(self.animation_duration)
      .attr('d', self.line);

    // Remove elements when data has been removed
    plot.exit().remove();

  };

  // Create the plot
  this.line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(self.defined)
    .x(self.domain_value)
    .y(self.range_value);

  // Add the plot
  this.svg = d3.select('.plotting-area').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

  // Build axes
  self.build_x_axis();
  self.build_y_axis();

}

var plot = new AreaPlot(800, 300);
plot.set_data([0.000001123356355492433, 0.0000016456004914289224, 0.00000365318737749476, 0.0000071284475779975764, 0.000011114293556602206, 0.000014993948752817232, 0.000018926746633951552, 0.00002390438567090314, 0.00003108202508883551, 0.000042029936594190076, 0.00005996139589115046, 0.00009308228618465364, 0.00015851244097575545, 0.00028807029593735933, 0.0005318910698406398, 0.0009597145835869014, 0.001658284803852439, 0.0027245471719652414, 0.004255148582160473, 0.006331713404506445, 0.009006175212562084, 0.012286805547773838, 0.01612810604274273, 0.02042604796588421, 0.025018742308020592, 0.02969328686594963, 0.03419889882206917, 0.038262657821178436, 0.04160662367939949, 0.04396504908800125, 0.04509869962930679, 0.04480859637260437, 0.042953010648489, 0.03945915400981903, 0.034325819462537766, 0.027618922293186188, 0.01946265622973442, 0.01002695132046938, -0.00048646843060851097, -0.011857914738357067, -0.023864813148975372, -0.03629292547702789, -0.04894426092505455, -0.06164303421974182, -0.07423866540193558, -0.08660601079463959, -0.09864328056573868, -0.11026866734027863, -0.12141597270965576, -0.13202965259552002, -0.1420600861310959, -0.1514589935541153, -0.1601753830909729, -0.16815230250358582, -0.17532429099082947, -0.18161560595035553, -0.18693871796131134, -0.19119326770305634, -0.19426564872264862, -0.19602838158607483, -0.19633722305297852, -0.1950329691171646, -0.1919592171907425, -0.18697473406791687, -0.17996013164520264, -0.17082466185092926, -0.15951387584209442, -0.1460162252187729, -0.13036656379699707, -0.11264725774526596, -0.09298709034919739, -0.07155791670084, -0.04856905713677406, -0.024260029196739197, 0.0011074095964431763, 0.027257222682237625, 0.053907610476017, 0.0807817280292511, 0.10760942101478577, 0.134135439991951, 0.16012170910835266, 0.1853480488061905, 0.20961420238018036, 0.23273740708827972, 0.2545509934425354, 0.2749021053314209, 0.29364922642707825, 0.3106593191623688, 0.32580533623695374, 0.3389641344547272, 0.3500145971775055, 0.3588365614414215, 0.36531007289886475, 0.36931514739990234, 0.3707317113876343, 0.3694346249103546, 0.3653166890144348, 0.35832133889198303, 0.3484494388103485, 0.3357595205307007, 0.320365846157074, 0.3024330735206604, 0.2821681499481201, 0.25981035828590393, 0.23561909794807434, 0.20986413955688477, 0.18281608819961548, 0.154735267162323, 0.12586426734924316, 0.09642627090215683, 0.06662261486053467, 0.036625660955905914, 0.0065885791555047035, -0.0233587808907032, -0.05309954658150673, -0.08253124356269836, -0.11156108230352402, -0.14010168612003326, -0.16806744039058685, -0.19537143409252167, -0.22192302346229553, -0.24762584269046783, -0.2723766267299652, -0.2960638403892517, -0.3185672461986542, -0.3397608697414398, -0.35950949788093567, -0.3776701092720032, -0.3940924406051636, -0.4086195230484009, -0.4210880994796753, -0.43132835626602173, -0.43916499614715576, -0.444417268037796, -0.4468980133533478, -0.446403831243515, -0.44274887442588806, -0.435820609331131, -0.42559346556663513, -0.41213077306747437, -0.39557990431785583, -0.37616103887557983, -0.35415124893188477, -0.32986560463905334, -0.3036372661590576, -0.2757995128631592, -0.24667039513587952, -0.21653911471366882, -0.1856570541858673, -0.1542341560125351, -0.12243901193141937, -0.09040120989084244, -0.058218248188495636, -0.02596207521855831, 0.006313909776508808, 0.03856449946761131, 0.07074491679668427, 0.10280267894268036, 0.13467101752758026, 0.16626420617103577, 0.1974746584892273, 0.22817173600196838, 0.25820192694664, 0.2873901128768921, 0.31554239988327026, 0.3424549102783203, 0.3679123520851135, 0.39169514179229736, 0.41358453035354614, 0.43336719274520874, 0.45083943009376526, 0.4658105671405792, 0.47810590267181396, 0.48756924271583557, 0.4940623342990875, 0.497466117143631, 0.4976797103881836, 0.4946165978908539, 0.4882490932941437, 0.478625625371933, 0.4658651053905487, 0.4501465857028961, 0.43169716000556946, 0.4107765853404999, 0.3876623511314392, 0.3626370429992676, 0.3359777629375458, 0.3079444468021393, 0.27877140045166016, 0.2486637979745865, 0.21780261397361755, 0.1863427460193634, 0.15441100299358368, 0.12211302667856216, 0.0895407497882843, 0.0567743256688118, 0.023883726447820663, -0.009063121862709522, -0.04199391230940819, -0.07483386993408203, -0.10750450938940048, -0.13991646468639374, -0.17197084426879883, -0.2035597264766693, -0.2345665544271469, -0.26486700773239136, -0.2943294048309326, -0.3228157162666321, -0.3501870632171631, -0.3762997090816498, -0.4010072350502014, -0.4241616129875183, -0.44561341404914856, -0.46521177887916565, -0.4828042984008789, -0.4982355833053589, -0.5113463997840881, -0.5219724178314209, -0.5299420952796936, -0.5350740551948547, -0.537172257900238, -0.5360098481178284, -0.5313860177993774, -0.5231779217720032, -0.5113512277603149, -0.4959602952003479, -0.47714266180992126, -0.4551066756248474, -0.43011534214019775, -0.40246710181236267, -0.3724800944328308, -0.34047189354896545, -0.3067466616630554, -0.2715858817100525, -0.2352415770292282, -0.19793124496936798, -0.15983843803405762, -0.12111887335777283, -0.08190887421369553, -0.04232468828558922, -0.002473345957696438, 0.037540458142757416, 0.0776071846485138, 0.1176062598824501, 0.15740123391151428, 0.1968364417552948, 0.2357352077960968, 0.2738995850086212, 0.3111116290092468, 0.34713315963745117, 0.3817175328731537, 0.41460666060447693, 0.4455369710922241, 0.4742451310157776, 0.5004726648330688, 0.5239704251289368, 0.5445020794868469, 0.5618473887443542, 0.5758042335510254, 0.586190402507782, 0.5928428769111633, 0.5956186652183533, 0.5943847894668579, 0.5890411734580994, 0.579584538936615, 0.5661150813102722, 0.5488259792327881, 0.5279880166053772, 0.5039304494857788, 0.4770186245441437, 0.44763463735580444, 0.41615986824035645, 0.3829595148563385, 0.348360538482666, 0.3126607835292816, 0.27611804008483887, 0.23894856870174408, 0.2013375610113144, 0.16342484951019287, 0.12533260881900787, 0.0871630534529686, 0.04899772256612778, 0.010911346413195133, -0.02702312171459198, -0.06473106890916824, -0.10213523358106613, -0.13914932310581207, -0.17567786574363708, -0.211615651845932, -0.24684767425060272, -0.2812497019767761, -0.3146892786026001, -0.3470252454280853, -0.37811198830604553, -0.407800555229187, -0.43593645095825195, -0.4623616933822632, -0.48691514134407043, -0.5094323754310608, -0.5297453999519348, -0.5476809144020081, -0.5630595088005066, -0.5756938457489014, -0.5853861570358276, -0.5919250249862671, -0.5950804948806763, -0.5945811867713928, -0.5901708602905273, -0.5816890001296997, -0.5690886974334717, -0.5524381399154663, -0.5319123864173889, -0.507776141166687, -0.4803611934185028, -0.4500406086444855, -0.4172038435935974, -0.382235586643219, -0.34549713134765625, -0.30731427669525146, -0.2679688334465027, -0.22770027816295624, -0.18669624626636505, -0.14511653780937195, -0.10308924317359924, -0.06072032451629639, -0.01810367777943611, 0.024667702615261078, 0.06749458611011505, 0.1102636530995369, 0.1528417319059372, 0.19507218897342682, 0.2367730289697647, 0.2777369022369385, 0.3177328109741211, 0.35650634765625, 0.3937927782535553, 0.4293144643306732, 0.46278759837150574, 0.4939286410808563, 0.5224599242210388, 0.5481139421463013, 0.570638120174408, 0.5897977352142334, 0.6053783297538757, 0.6171870827674866, 0.6250532865524292, 0.628827691078186, 0.6283743977546692, 0.6235799193382263, 0.6144271492958069, 0.6010120511054993, 0.5835336446762085, 0.5622765421867371, 0.537590742111206, 0.5098663568496704, 0.47951263189315796, 0.4469384551048279, 0.4125331938266754, 0.3766525387763977, 0.3396112620830536, 0.30168434977531433, 0.2631017565727234, 0.22405900061130524, 0.18470248579978943, 0.1451607644557953, 0.10553813725709915, 0.06591808050870895, 0.02637604810297489, -0.01301523670554161, -0.0521814338862896, -0.09104548394680023, -0.1295214295387268, -0.1675138920545578, -0.20491750538349152, -0.2416168600320816, -0.2774871289730072, -0.3123950958251953, -0.34619879722595215, -0.3787517845630646, -0.40990427136421204, -0.43950122594833374, -0.4673842191696167, -0.4933919906616211, -0.5173600316047668, -0.5391202569007874, -0.558499813079834, -0.5753192901611328, -0.5893915295600891, -0.6005186438560486, -0.6084887981414795, -0.613072395324707, -0.6140021681785583, -0.6109884977340698, -0.6038209795951843, -0.5924047827720642, -0.5767669081687927, -0.5570509433746338, -0.533501923084259, -0.5064438581466675, -0.4762532711029053, -0.44333186745643616, -0.40808290243148804, -0.37089109420776367, -0.3321075141429901, -0.2920394539833069, -0.2509482502937317, -0.2090442031621933, -0.1665026992559433, -0.12346445769071579, -0.0800449326634407, -0.036342669278383255, 0.00754685141146183, 0.051524728536605835, 0.09547996520996094, 0.13928285241127014, 0.18278059363365173, 0.22579479217529297, 0.2681208848953247, 0.30952945351600647, 0.34976696968078613, 0.38856440782546997, 0.4256414771080017, 0.46070876717567444, 0.4934753477573395, 0.5236546993255615, 0.5509694814682007, 0.5751563906669617, 0.5959693193435669, 0.613182544708252, 0.6265919208526611, 0.6360159516334534, 0.6412951350212097, 0.6422881484031677, 0.6388635039329529, 0.6309658288955688, 0.6186575889587402, 0.602112352848053, 0.581598699092865, 0.5574603080749512, 0.5300900340080261, 0.49990710616111755, 0.4673348367214203, 0.43278542160987854, 0.39663606882095337, 0.3592229187488556, 0.32084205746650696, 0.28174322843551636, 0.24213548004627228, 0.20218481123447418, 0.1620236188173294, 0.12176717072725296, 0.08150387555360794, 0.041310567408800125, 0.0012598168104887009, -0.03857453167438507, -0.07811757922172546, -0.1172863319516182, -0.15598851442337036, -0.19412188231945038, -0.2315739244222641, -0.2682223618030548, -0.3039361238479614, -0.3385757803916931, -0.3719944357872009, -0.40404364466667175, -0.43456903100013733, -0.46341243386268616, -0.4904126226902008, -0.5154051780700684, -0.5382221341133118, -0.5586912035942078, -0.5766334533691406, -0.5918626189231873, -0.6041821837425232, -0.6133822798728943, -0.6192360520362854, -0.6214874982833862, -0.6198368072509766, -0.6140332818031311, -0.6039385795593262, -0.5895386338233948, -0.5709421634674072, -0.5483677387237549, -0.5221231579780579, -0.4925788342952728, -0.460139662027359, -0.4252186119556427, -0.3882159888744354, -0.349501371383667, -0.3094020187854767, -0.26819726824760437, -0.22611777484416962, -0.18334870040416718, -0.1400429904460907, -0.09632275253534317, -0.0522911511361599, -0.00804352667182684, 0.03632388263940811, 0.08070484548807144, 0.12497598677873611, 0.1689915955066681, 0.21258056163787842, 0.2555451989173889, 0.2976619005203247, 0.33868274092674255, 0.37833932042121887, 0.4163532257080078, 0.452434241771698, 0.4862886667251587, 0.5176253318786621, 0.5461611151695251, 0.5716253519058228, 0.5937641859054565, 0.6123433113098145, 0.6271498799324036, 0.6379938721656799, 0.6447076201438904, 0.6471443176269531, 0.6451656222343445, 0.6386816501617432, 0.6277171969413757, 0.6124131679534912, 0.5930125713348389, 0.5698412656784058, 0.5432835817337036, 0.5137575268745422, 0.4816920757293701, 0.44750866293907166, 0.4116024374961853, 0.3743250370025635, 0.33598896861076355, 0.2968609035015106, 0.257163941860199, 0.21707779169082642, 0.17674489319324493, 0.13628710806369781, 0.09580041468143463, 0.055364079773426056, 0.015051072463393211, -0.025065138936042786, -0.0649108737707138, -0.10440607368946075, -0.14346158504486084, -0.18197837471961975, -0.21984706819057465, -0.2569483816623688, -0.29315370321273804, -0.32832643389701843, -0.3623214066028595, -0.3949895203113556, -0.4261786937713623, -0.45573174953460693, -0.4834882318973541, -0.5092844367027283, -0.5329533815383911, -0.5543240308761597, -0.5732192993164062, -0.5894550681114197, -0.6028378009796143, -0.6131618022918701, -0.6202048659324646, -0.6237227916717529, -0.6234235763549805, -0.619025707244873, -0.6103493571281433, -0.5973377227783203, -0.5800597667694092, -0.558700680732727, -0.5335433483123779, -0.5049428343772888, -0.4732985198497772, -0.4390256702899933, -0.40253376960754395, -0.3642062544822693, -0.3243873119354248, -0.28337332606315613, -0.2414136677980423, -0.19870540499687195, -0.15541407465934753, -0.11167067289352417, -0.06758324801921844, -0.023248950019478798, 0.02123735472559929, 0.06577356159687042, 0.11024246364831924, 0.1545058935880661, 0.19840092957019806, 0.24173812568187714, 0.28430160880088806, 0.32585087418556213, 0.3661213517189026, 0.4048379957675934, 0.44171249866485596, 0.4764506220817566, 0.5087589025497437, 0.5383500456809998, 0.5649480819702148, 0.5882924795150757, 0.6081414222717285, 0.6242743730545044, 0.6364930868148804, 0.6446221470832825, 0.6485080122947693, 0.6480104327201843, 0.6430124044418335, 0.6334987282752991, 0.6195735335350037, 0.6014490723609924, 0.5794275403022766, 0.5538786053657532, 0.5252132415771484, 0.49386104941368103, 0.4602498710155487, 0.4247856140136719, 0.38783782720565796, 0.34973233938217163, 0.31075236201286316, 0.27113354206085205, 0.23107554018497467, 0.19072695076465607, 0.15021662414073944, 0.1096506118774414, 0.06911144405603409, 0.028673723340034485, -0.011590387672185898, -0.05160680413246155, -0.09129855036735535, -0.13057954609394073, -0.16935409605503082, -0.20751625299453735, -0.24494986236095428, -0.2815292179584503, -0.31712013483047485, -0.35158050060272217, -0.38476109504699707, -0.4165118336677551, -0.44667667150497437, -0.47509610652923584, -0.5016074180603027, -0.5260446667671204, -0.5482381582260132, -0.5680128335952759, -0.5851869583129883, -0.5995701551437378, -0.610960841178894, -0.6191422939300537, -0.6238790154457092, -0.6248956322669983, -0.6218920946121216, -0.6146496534347534, -0.6030692458152771, -0.5871784090995789, -0.5671254992485046, -0.543164074420929, -0.515629231929779, -0.4849095940589905, -0.4514192044734955, -0.4155726730823517, -0.37776464223861694, -0.3383543789386749, -0.29765525460243225, -0.25593292713165283, -0.21340012550354004, -0.1702335774898529, -0.1265745759010315, -0.08253772556781769, -0.038222476840019226, 0.006276535801589489, 0.050860557705163956, 0.09541812539100647, 0.1398184895515442, 0.18390712141990662, 0.22750329971313477, 0.2703996002674103, 0.3123631477355957, 0.3531356155872345, 0.39244645833969116, 0.4300101101398468, 0.465533047914505, 0.49872052669525146, 0.5292823910713196, 0.5569380521774292, 0.5814211368560791, 0.6024831533432007, 0.6198959946632385, 0.6334537267684937, 0.6429732441902161, 0.6482937932014465, 0.6492726802825928, 0.6457772254943848, 0.6377527713775635, 0.6252648234367371, 0.6084917783737183, 0.5877084136009216, 0.5632656216621399, 0.5355637669563293, 0.5050294399261475, 0.47209271788597107, 0.4371717572212219, 0.4006486237049103, 0.36286330223083496, 0.32411476969718933, 0.2846544682979584, 0.24469275772571564, 0.20439627766609192, 0.16389751434326172, 0.12331195175647736, 0.08272752165794373, 0.04222084581851959, 0.0018642479553818703, -0.038268573582172394, -0.07810275256633759, -0.11755528301000595, -0.15653371810913086, -0.19493556022644043, -0.23264797031879425, -0.26954832673072815, -0.3055051565170288, -0.34037917852401733, -0.37402209639549255, -0.4062851071357727, -0.43701377511024475, -0.4660496711730957, -0.4932311177253723, -0.5183932185173035, -0.5413675308227539, -0.5619811415672302, -0.5800544619560242, -0.5954000949859619, -0.6078205704689026, -0.6171044707298279, -0.6230231523513794, -0.6253182291984558, -0.6236864924430847, -0.6178737878799438, -0.6077395081520081, -0.5932689309120178, -0.5745716094970703, -0.5518685579299927, -0.5254707932472229, -0.4957526624202728, -0.4631232023239136, -0.42799946665763855, -0.39078524708747864, -0.35185325145721436, -0.311533123254776, -0.2701060175895691, -0.22780375182628632, -0.18481211364269257, -0.14128455519676208, -0.09734328091144562, -0.053091470152139664, -0.008624481968581676, 0.03596140444278717, 0.08055977523326874, 0.12504689395427704, 0.16927646100521088, 0.21307659149169922, 0.2562486231327057, 0.2985678017139435, 0.3397839069366455, 0.3796292543411255, 0.4178231954574585, 0.45407381653785706, 0.4880860447883606, 0.5195674896240234, 0.5482336282730103, 0.5738129615783691, 0.5960504412651062, 0.6147108674049377, 0.6295807957649231, 0.6404695510864258, 0.6472087502479553, 0.6496512293815613, 0.6476582288742065, 0.6411396265029907, 0.6301207542419434, 0.6147440671920776, 0.5952546000480652, 0.5719805955886841, 0.5453091263771057, 0.5156607031822205, 0.4834669232368469, 0.4491514265537262, 0.4131113588809967, 0.3756999671459198, 0.3372308909893036, 0.2979716658592224, 0.2581459581851959, 0.21793389320373535, 0.17747801542282104, 0.13690036535263062, 0.09629671275615692, 0.055746305733919144, 0.015322037972509861, -0.024902716279029846, -0.06485427916049957, -0.10445264726877213, -0.14360862970352173, -0.18222306668758392, -0.22018659114837646, -0.2573797106742859, -0.2936737835407257, -0.328931987285614, -0.3630090355873108, -0.39575570821762085, -0.42701980471611023, -0.4566440284252167, -0.48446768522262573, -0.5103269815444946, -0.5340547561645508, -0.5554797649383545, -0.574424684047699, -0.5907049775123596, -0.6041268110275269, -0.6144838929176331, -0.6215535402297974, -0.6250906586647034, -0.6248021721839905, -0.6204051971435547, -0.6117189526557922, -0.5986862182617188, -0.5813759565353394, -0.559974193572998]);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.axis line {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke: #000;
}

.grid line {
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-opacity: 0.65;
}

.grid .minor line {
  stroke-opacity: 0.35;
  stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
}

.grid text {
  display: none;
}

.grid path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class='plotting-area'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, the tricky part was that if you check your `set_data` method/function you will find something like this:

```
this.set_data = function(data) {
    // Update data extents
    self.x.domain([0, data.length]);
    self.y.domain(d3.extent(data));
    // Update line
    self.update_line(data);
    // Update axes with our new data
    self.update_axes();
    // Printing new tick values for better understanding
    10ticks [-0.6000000000000001, -0.5000000000000001, -0.4000000000000001, -0.3000000000000001, -0.2000000000000001, -0.10000000000000009, -8.881784197001253e-17, 0.09999999999999991, 0.1999999999999999, 0.29999999999999993, 0.3999999999999999, 0.4999999999999999, 0.5999999999999999]
    20ticks [-0.6000000000000001, -0.55, -0.5000000000000001, -0.45000000000000007, -0.4000000000000001, -0.3500000000000001, -0.30000000000000004, -0.25000000000000006, -0.20000000000000007, -0.15000000000000008, -0.10000000000000007, -0.05000000000000007, -7.105427357601002e-17, 0.049999999999999926, 0.09999999999999992, 0.14999999999999994, 0.19999999999999993, 0.24999999999999992, 0.29999999999999993, 0.3499999999999999, 0.3999999999999999, 0.44999999999999996, 0.49999999999999994, 0.5499999999999999, 0.6]
}
```

Then in your update `update_axes` method/function you call `style_y_grid(self.y_grid_g);` which is defined like this:

```
this.style_y_grid = function(g) {
    g.selectAll('.tick') // get all ticks in grid
    .data(self.y.ticks(10), function(d) { // get all the values from the 10ticks array and use them as data
        return d;
    })
    .exit()
    .classed('minor', true);
}
```

So what is the issue? Well since you are using `selections` and the `data` function which joins the specified array of data with the current selection. Since the value of the data you are using for that selection is the mere value of your ticks that will give you a matching error. Your grid tick elements are joined with the 20ticks values and you are trying to update with new values (10ticks) that differ from the previous ones. Why?, lets check this out:

```
var tens = [-0.6000000000000001, -0.5000000000000001, -0.4000000000000001, -0.3000000000000001, -0.2000000000000001, -0.10000000000000009, -8.881784197001253e-17, 0.09999999999999991, 0.1999999999999999, 0.29999999999999993, 0.3999999999999999, 0.4999999999999999, 0.5999999999999999];
var twenties = [-0.6000000000000001, -0.55, -0.5000000000000001, -0.45000000000000007, -0.4000000000000001, -0.3500000000000001, -0.30000000000000004, -0.25000000000000006, -0.20000000000000007, -0.15000000000000008, -0.10000000000000007, -0.05000000000000007, -7.105427357601002e-17, 0.049999999999999926, 0.09999999999999992, 0.14999999999999994, 0.19999999999999993, 0.24999999999999992, 0.29999999999999993, 0.3499999999999999, 0.3999999999999999, 0.44999999999999996, 0.49999999999999994, 0.5499999999999999, 0.6];

var result = _.intersection(tens, twenties);
[-0.6000000000000001, -0.5000000000000001, -0.4000000000000001, 0.29999999999999993, 0.3999999999999999]
```

The values are the ticks you see as 'major' ticks in your y-grid. But hey, why does the [-1, 1] scale works? Lets make the previous example but with the new scale value.

```
var tens = [-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1];
var twenties = [-1, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
var result = _.intersection(tens, twenties);
[-1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
```

Hope that this made clear the issue. If you need a simple approach you can basically do this which will take all the 20 ticks of your grid and class just the half of them.

```
this.style_y_grid = function(g) {
    g.selectAll('.tick')
    .data(self.y.ticks(20), function(d, i) {
        if(i % 2 === 0) return d;
    })
    .exit()
    .classed('minor', true);
};
```

Plunkr: https://jsfiddle.net/z3r8ewmL/4/